# Como pasar parámetros personalizados en una petición http con HttpClient a un HttpInterceptor en Angular

Tags: angularjs-2.0

he estado probando el nuevo módulo **HttpClient** de angular, y se me ocurrió una idea muy especifica haciendo uso de los **HttpInterceptor**, pero para lograrla necesito mandar una configuración adicional en el momento de realizar la **petición**, pero no he podido encontrar una solución, mas o menos lo que deseo es lo siguiente:

```
this.http.get(`api/`, {myData: 'alguna cosa'})
```

Como pueden apreciar en el anterior ejemplo necesito pasar "myData" para realizar ciertas acciones en el **Interceptor** pero no tengo la menor idea de como hacer esto.

Comment: Desconozco la manera de pasarle datos que no tengan que ver con la petición pero te puedo aportar otra solución: envia en el cuerpo de tu peticion tu objeto, lo recoges en tu interceptor lo tratas lo eliminas del cuerpo y clonas peticion con el nuevo cuerpo sin la conf.

Comment: Hola pensé en algo parecido, disculpa mi ignorancia pero ¿puedo utilizar la key “body” con una petición get ?

Comment: En el caso del método GET podrías incluir en la URL un JSON como string con los datos que necesitas enviar a tu interceptor y ya luego en tu interceptor limpiar estos datos durante el clonado. http://localhost:8000/api?conf={myData:'alguna cosa'}

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo quieres tratar el cuerpo de la petición antes de enviarla, entonces en tu interceptor recoge el `body` o `params` del objeto request, trátalos y luego clona el request original y establece los nuevos valores que necesitas más lo que habían.

```
@Injectable()
export class TuInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const method = req.method;
    const url = req.url;
    const body = req.body;
    const headers = req.headers;
    // ...
    req = req.clone({method, url, body, headers});
    // ...
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola, mira lo que estoy tratando de hacer es agregar parámetros adicionales que no tienen nada que ver con la petición, por ende no los puedo enviar ni en el body o params, son datos extras que quiero usar en el intersector para tomar una decisión: 
Paso 1: this.http.get(`url`, {myConfig: 'datos personalizados'})
Paso 2:  en el interceptor quiero acceder a {myConfig: 'datos personalizados'}

Comment: El problema que veo es que no puedo mandar esos parámetros personalizados porque el tipado de datos no me deja ya que solo se permiten estos parámetros en las opciones: 
options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders;
    observe?: "body";
    params?: HttpParams;
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType: "arraybuffer";
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}

Comment: Según la declaración de las clases del interceptor, de la peticion y del cliente http no hay manera de pasar una configuración propia más allá de extender la clase HttpRequest con la tuya propia añadiendo las funcionalidades que necesites.

Answer (score 0):

Exactamente esto, comunicacion service a interceptor, es uno de los puntos debiles de la nueva API. Una opcion, que no considero optima, es mandar parametros a travez de custom headers. Por ejemplo:

```
@Injectable()
export class FooInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const param = req.headers.get('params');
    if(param){ // parameter seteado
      // remover custom header para no enviar basura al back end
      headers = req.headers.delete('params');
      // clonar request original sin el custom header
      req = req.clone({
        headers   
      });
    }
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

Un ejemplo de como mandar este parametro al interceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class FooService {
  ctor(private http: HttpClient){}

  get(): Observable<FooInterface> {
   const headers = new HttpHeaders({'params':'valor'});
   return this.get<FooInterface>("url",{headers});
  }
}
```

Otro ejemplo del mismo concepto puede ser visto [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45938931/angular-httpclient-default-and-specific-request-timeout)